# Type Error when sending command through python

Tags: python, unicode

I'm trying to use bleualign (https://github.com/rsennrich/Bleualign) to align the sentences of some .txt files. The way this tool works is to send a command in the terminal in the following way:

```
python ../../Bleualign/bleualign.py -s circle_en-us_pre_aligned.txt -t circle_pt-br_pre_aligned.txt --srctotarget - -o output
```

The names of the files are specific to what I'm doing. THIS works if I use it directly on the terminal.

However, when I try to do it through python,

```
def align_sentences(folder_name, src_lang, trgt_lang):

    string = u"python ../../Bleualign/bleualign.py -s "+\
        folder_name+u"_"+src_lang+u"_pre_align.txt "+\
        u"-t "+folder_name+u"_"+trgt_lang+u"_pre_align.txt "+\
        u"--srctotarget -"+\
        u" -o outputfile"


    os.system(string)
```

When I:

```
align_sentences(u"circle",u"en-us",u"pt-br")
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "../../Bleualign/bleualign.py", line 14, in <module>
    a = Aligner(options)



File "/home/goncalo/Bleualign/bleualign/align.py", line 159, in __init__
    self._inputObjectFromParameter(self.options['srcfile'])
  File "/home/goncalo/Bleualign/bleualign/align.py", line 198, in _inputObjectFromParameter
    inputObject = self._stringArray2stringIo(parameter)
  File "/home/goncalo/Bleualign/bleualign/align.py", line 187, in _stringArray2stringIo
    return io.StringIO('\n'.join([line.rstrip() for line in stringArray]))
TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str
```

As you see I've tried to convert the string to unicode by adding 'u' before the strings. I also did it without the u, using unicode(), tried .decode()...

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Bleualign.  On the current line of https://github.com/rsennrich/Bleualign/blob/master/bleualign/align.py#L187 the authors have:

```
return io.StringIO('\n'.join([line.rstrip() for line in stringArray]))
```

This eventually gets the options parameter in `__init__` here https://github.com/rsennrich/Bleualign/blob/master/bleualign/align.py#L159

Which passes a String `"srcfile"` which is not a unicode string. So the join function combines two non-unicode strings to make another non-unicode string which `io.StringIO` rejects.  The authors likely need to just change the option parameter to `u"srcfile"`.

I would file an issue on their Github page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will do that.

Comment: @GonçaloCorreia did you have any luck with this?  I'm running into the same problem